# Git workflow for html/css and javascript mvvm framework integration separate repos

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, vue.js

Currently in my project I have this situation:

We have one repo(r1) which is being used by UI designer for html/css part of the front end(With some minor javascript).

I clone this repo r1 to my local system(say l1).

I will need to integrate javascript framework (react or vue.js) using the front end from r1 and then push the resulting code to another repository (r2).

Currently I am having to copy the code from l1 to another local git repo l2(which points to r2) as and when the designer updates r1.

Is there a way I could avoid this copy and pasting?

PS: We do not want the designer having to update his repo r1 with anything from r2

Comment: May I ask why you have the UI work in a separate repo?

Comment: Company policy unfortunately @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

It seems your team is not familiar with `branchs` commands , namely :

- git merge
- git merge origin/[BRANCH] filePath
- git checkout origin/[BRANCH] filePath

So, create `branchs` instead of `repos` :

```
                   master
                     |
                    dev
                     |
                    / \
                   /   \
                  r1   r2
```

Now assuming `r1` is the branch of UI and `r2` is your branch (JS).

So follow these steps :

- Checkout JS branch (instead of cloning a repo) :

  ```
    git fetch && git checkout r2 ;
  ```
- Checkout UI branch (instead of cloning a repo) :

  ```
    git fetch && git checkout r1 ;
  ```

Now , the 2 branches are downloaded locally.

- Go to your branch :

  ```
    git checkout r2;
  ```
- Merge `r1` with r2 :

  ```
    git merge origin/r1 ;
  ```

#### Use Case

If UI team makes changes  and you are in your branch `r2` :

```
     git checkout r1;
     git pull # download changes of r1
     git checkout r2; #go back to your r2
      
     git merge origin/r1; #merge code of r1 with the current branch which is r2
```

Comment: I don't think the team has kept repos separate as they don't know about branches. Most likely they don't want ui team to have access to r2 due to maybe confidentiality. But anyways, I have upvoted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you should do is have the l1 fetch data from the remote of r1, and have the remote for your l1 push data to r2. Instead of copying everything from l1 to l2, I would just eliminate l2 completely and change those remote URLs.

The Github link describing how to change the remote URLs for reference is https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

If you have your l1 connected to the r1 repo's current remote URL, all you need to do is set your push remote URL to the remote URL of your r2 with the command

```
git remote set-url --push [remotename] [remoteURL]
```

you can check your remote URL's before and after the change with

```
git remote -v
```

and if you are having trouble with the git remote commands, just make sure you are in your l1 working directory and use:

```
git remote help
```

This way when you get data in your l1 local system it will come from the developer. You can integrate the code/do your thing, and when you go to commit those changes they will be committed to your r2 like you wanted.

I hope that helps!